# Error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pyparsing>=1.5.5')

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04, pyparsing

I want to install the charm cryptography library on my Ubuntu (16.04) and the python version is 2.7.12. While I meet a error like this when executing `make install`.

```
No local packages or download links found for pyparsing>=1.5.5
error: Could not find suitable distribution for
Requirement.parse('pyparsing>=1.5.5')
Makefile:97: recipe for target 'install' failed
```

This is the output info when executing `make install` command.

```
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing Charm_Crypto-0.42-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
removing '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Charm_Crypto-0.42-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg' (and everything under it)
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Charm_Crypto-0.42-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Extracting Charm_Crypto-0.42-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Charm-Crypto 0.42 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Charm_Crypto-0.42-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for Charm-Crypto==0.42
Searching for pyparsing>=1.5.5
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pyparsing/
Couldn't find index page for 'pyparsing' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for pyparsing>=1.5.5
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pyparsing>=1.5.5')
Makefile:97: recipe for target 'install' failed
```

I have tried to fix this error and google some solution, someone said I should install pip and python setuptools and then install an old version of pyparsing (1.5.7). But this will appear another error also about pyparsing. I show the files under the folder `python2.7/dist-packages` as following.

```
root@rocky-VirtualBox:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages# ls
Charm_Crypto-0.42-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg  pyparsing-1.5.7.dist-info
distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg               pyparsing.py
easy-install.pth                          pyparsing.pyc
easy_install.py                           setuptools
easy_install.pyc                          setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info
pip                                       setuptools-38.4.0.dist-info
pip-9.0.1.dist-info                       setuptools.pth
pkg_resources
```

There is already some files named `pyparsing-1.5.7.dist-info` and `pyparsing.py`, but why terminal still claim that "Couldn't find index page for 'pyparsing'"? Hoping you can help me if you meet this error before.

Comment: I don't see any advantage in installing an old version of pyparsing. The latest version 2.2.0 is compatible with Python 2.7. Try manually installing that version first, which should satisfy the `>= 1.5.5` requirement.

Comment: Well, yes, agree with you, I have installed the version 2.2.0 under the /local/lib/python2.7 folder by the command 'pip install pyparsing==2.2.0' . but the same error still appears. No local packages or download links found for pyparsing>=1.5.5

Comment: The pyparsing-2.2.0. dist-info has appeared under the /lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ folder. why it still reminds that "No local packages or download links found for pyparsing>=1.5.5"?

Comment: I think I have found the reason. The key issue is the setup.py. There is one sentence announced that the pyparsing version needs to be checked from the http://pypi.python.org/simple/pyparsing/. but actually it has been installed. I comment out this sentence in the setup.py and then fix it. The Charm has been installed and run 'make test' successfully.